# will there be a delay in sending email for different id's

Tags: apex-email-service

I have  two contacts for which the  email id's are say `123@abc.com` for contact1 amd `234@xyz.com` for contact2. When I send Email Message to `123@abc.com`, I'm getting the email immediately. Whereas the email sent to `234@xyz.com` is taking about 2 to 3 hours to get delivered. what can be the reason for this?

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: The reason could be completely outside of salesforce, and perhaps more in the realm of SMTP and POP protocols. Do you experience the same delay when sending via another mail client or via a handcrafted program in another language?

Comment: Hi mkorman,
I did not try sending the email using another program.So can we be sure that this issue is not related to Salesforce.
Thanks

Comment: The only way to make sure is to try it :)